# Haskell adding Vectors and dot product

Tags: haskell, dot-product

the tasks are:

1. Write a function that adds vectors
2. A function that calculates the dot product
3. A function that can use the dot product to determine whether the angle is right.

My approaches:

1. .

   ```
   addVectors:: (Num a) => a -> a -> a
   addVectors (a1, a2, a3) (b1, b2, b3) = (a1 + b1) (a2 + b2) (a3 + b3)
   ```
2. .

   ```
   scalarProduct:: (Num a) => a -> a -> a 
   scalarProduct (a1, a2, a3) (b1, b2, b3) = (a1 * b1) (a2 * b2) (a3 * b3)
   ```
3. ?

So I'm not sure how to phrase it. In the end, true should come out. This is likely to happen if the dot product equals 0.

I tried approaching tasks 1 and 2 myself.

Comment: Both your `addVector` and `scalarProduct` are wrong, as the compiler should have told you already. — It seems like you still need to get acquainted with basic concepts of Haskell, like what tuples are (you call them “vectors” but that's not the same thing, I suggest you say “3-tuples representing ℝ³”). Please properly read a basic tutorial like [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) before asking questions. Also, when you do ask a question, make it about a concrete problem you've encountered while trying to get _one_ function working.

Comment: could you show me how you would express the vector addition function so I have a general idea of ​​what it should look like?

Comment: `f :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a` is the wrong type. This claims that `f` can be used on all numeric types, e.g. `f 32 45` must work. Maybe you want something more like `f :: Num a => (a,a,a) -> (a,a,a) -> (a,a,a)`, claiming that it will work on 3-tuples (of any numeric type). Also note that you need to return a tuple, as in `f ... = ( ... , ... , ...)`.

Comment: From what I understood I did: addVectors:: (Num a) => (a, a ,a) -> (a, a, a) -> (a, a, a)
addVectors (a1, a2, a3) (b1, b2, b3) = (a1 + b1) (a2 + b2) (a3 + b3) -still doesnt work

Comment: Well, why would `(...) (...) (...)` work? You're trying to build a tuple here, right? So you should perhaps use tuple syntax.

Comment: If 3-tuples actually had a `Num` instance, you wouldn't need to define `addVectors`: `+` would already work. (That's part of the *definition* of having a `Num` instance.)

Comment: `(a1 + b1) (a2 + b2) (a3 + b3)` doesn't have any `,`s in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone is dancing around this, but I'm going to be explicit.

```
addVectors (a1, a2, a3) (b1, b2, b3) = (a1 + b1) (a2 + b2) (a3 + b3)
```

Your output is not valid tuple syntax.

You must instead write

```
addVectors (a1, a2, a3) (b1, b2, b3) = (a1 + b1, a2 + b2, a3 + b3)
```

Comment: Finally, thanks ^^